# proxy error occured while switching to webview from native through appium in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, webview, proxy, appium

when i'm trying to switch from native context to webview context through appium in my script

```
Set<String> contextNames =AndroidLib.driver.getContextHandles();
            for (String contextName : contextNames) {
                Logger.printDebug("contextName:"+contextName);
              if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
                  AndroidLib.driver.context(contextName);
              }
            }
            Logger.printDebug("current Context:"+AndroidLib.driver.getContext());
```

i'm getting proxy error as below:

> Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original
>   error: 502 -!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
>   Transitional//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Note: when i'm running the same script in my windows machine it works fine...its switching wo webView context and performing actions.I'm guessing something wrong with my MAC machine or something related to proxy...couldn't figure it out....scratching my head...Please let me know the reason for this error and provide me a solution

Sooner response would be much appreciated :-) :-)

Comment: to what i remember, this could probably be an issue with chromedriver or some older version of appium, what version on MAC are you using for these?

Comment: MAC version : 10.10.5 (14F1605) ; Chromedriver version -- 2.21 ;; Appium version -- 1.5

Comment: @nullpointer can you please give an update on this

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this issue